# mousover mouseout this class visible hidden pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Each text belongs to a specific image, so when someone is moving the cursor  over that image. The text should be shown up and when the cursor goes mouseout the text should be hidden. No jQuerty required please, must be in pure JavaScript. Anyone an idea how I should fix that.

```js
function show() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("text").style.visibility = "visible";
} 

function hide() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("text").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tumb-wrapper">
      <a href="www.bbc.com" target="_blank" class="image" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()">
      <img src="img/a-print-screen.png" class="project" alt="a-print-screen"/>
       <div class="text">A-picture</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tumb-wrapper">
      <a href="www.cnn.com" target="_blank" class="image" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()">
      <img src="img/x-picture.png" class="project" alt="x-print-screen"/>
      <div class="text">x-picture</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList

Comment: You want the image to appear when the cursor is above the link and to disappear, when it's gone?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The text should be appeared when the cursor is moving over that image.

Comment: You want to loop through the node list. Unless you want to one element of that class then you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0]` but since you have multiple elements with that class I can only assume you want this to function for all elements.  OR you can target the closest element with that class name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `document.getElementsByClassName("text");` returns a List of elements opposed to `document.getElementById("text");` which returns just one element.
So to use one element to change its style you have to use array notation `document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0]` for example for the first element.

I used a for loop to iterate over every list element in the code sample below:

```js
function show(myText) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(myText)
  
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].style.visibility = "visible";
  }
} 

function hide(myText) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(myText)
  
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tumb-wrapper">
      <a href="www.bbc.com" target="_blank" class="image" >
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300&fm=png" class="project" alt="a-print-screen" onmouseover="show('text1')" onmouseout="hide('text1')"/>
        <div class="text1">A-picture</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tumb-wrapper">
      <a href="www.cnn.com" target="_blank" class="image" >
        <img src="https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DHC_blog-image-01-300x300.jpg" class="project" alt="x-print-screen" onmouseover="show('text2')" onmouseout="hide('text2')" />
        <div class="text2">x-picture</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost there, but both text are showing up. No matter which image you hover.

Comment: Now it should be the desired behaviour. I also changed the events into the images. I felt it was a bit more accurate.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!